# I can't set parameters in java using Oracle Sql query

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle

I have a database Oracle 12 and query 'ALTER USER GISDPFB SET DEFAULT TABLESPACE DEV_MDS'
Query is correct and i can execute it manually,but I can't to set parameters dynamically.
My Code:

```
 callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("ALTER USER ? DEFAULT TABLESPACE ?");
    callableStatement.setString(1,"John");
    callableStatement.setString(2,"SYSAUX");
    callableStatement.execute();
```

I got 'java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01935: missing user or role name'

I guess this exception because of wrong syntax,but i have success when do it in console

Answer (score 3):

You can only use bind variables for values, not identifiers - which both the user name and tablespace name are. You'll need to embed them in the statement:

```
callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("ALTER USER \"John\" DEFAULT TABLESPACE \"SYSAUX\"");
callableStatement.execute();
```

or if the values are coming from Java variables:

```
callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("ALTER USER \"" + userName
  + "\" DEFAULT TABLESPACE \"" + tablespaceName + "\"");
callableStatement.execute();
```

If they are from variables you might want to look at adding [`dbms_assert`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_ASSERT.html) checks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure `ALTER USER` is considered DLL and doesn't take bind variables. You'll probably have to just create a string for it. Try:

```
callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("ALTER USER john DEFAULT TABLESPACE SYSAUX");
callableStatement.execute();
```

Comment: can you give me advice,what kind of query you would use for my case for Oracle?I need to use  bind variables(?,?)

Comment: You could check out this answer, by essentially wrapping the `ALTER USER` in `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`. I haven't verified that it works. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315170/execute-immediate-alter-user-bind-variable